# Stack Corruption Warning in C++ using mysql C API prepared statement

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a helper function for using prepared statements with mysql. All works well as long as i dont want to retrieve any results.

If i want to retrieve a result (e.g. simple long ID) im getting a warning from visual studio debugger that the stack is corrupted around my ID variable.

Header
bool    RunPreparedStatement(std::string query, std::vector paramList, std::string& errbuf, int* affected_rows, bool fetchResultID = false, int32* result_id=0, bool fetchInsertID = false, int32* last_insert_id=0);

```
bool RunPreparedStatement(std::string sql, std::vector<MYSQL_BIND> paramList, std::string& errStr, int* affected_rows, bool fetchResultID, int32* result_id, bool fetchInsertID, int32* last_insert_id) {
char errbuf[MYSQL_ERRMSG_SIZE];

int numParams = paramList.size();

bool fetchResult = fetchResultID;

if(numParams == 0) {
    errStr = "0 parameters supplied";        
    return false;
}

MYSQL_STMT *stmt = mysql_stmt_init(&mysql);

if (!stmt) {
    errStr = "mysql_stmt_init(), out of memory";         
    return false;
}

if (mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, sql.c_str(), sql.length())) {
    errStr =  "mysql_stmt_prepare() failed ";
    errStr.append(mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
    return false;
}

int param_count= mysql_stmt_param_count(stmt);

if (param_count != numParams) /* validate parameter count */{
    errStr = "invalid parameter count returned by MySQL";
    return false;
}

if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, &paramList[0])) {
    errStr = "mysql_stmt_bind_param() failed ";
    errStr.append(mysql_stmt_error(stmt));  
    return false;
}

int32 id = 0;
MYSQL_BIND resultParam1;    
BindValue(&resultParam1,MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG,&id,0,0,0);

if(fetchResult) {                       
     /* Bind the results buffer */
  if (mysql_stmt_bind_result(stmt,  &resultParam1) != 0) {      
    errStr = "mysql_stmt_bind_result() failed ";
    errStr.append(mysql_stmt_error(stmt));  
    return false;
  }
}

if (mysql_stmt_execute(stmt)) {
    errStr = "mysql_stmt_execute() failed ";
    errStr.append(mysql_stmt_error(stmt));          
    return false;
}

if(fetchResult) {

    if (mysql_stmt_store_result(stmt) != 0) {         
        errStr = "Could not buffer result set ";
        errStr.append(mysql_stmt_error(stmt));      
        return false;
    }

  if(mysql_stmt_fetch (stmt) == 0) {

      (*result_id) = id;

    // OK
      *affected_rows = 1;
  } else {      
      *affected_rows = 0;
    /*errStr = "no results found ";
    errStr.append(mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
    return false;*/
  }
} else {
    *affected_rows = mysql_stmt_affected_rows(stmt);        
}

if(fetchInsertID) {
    *last_insert_id= mysql_stmt_insert_id(stmt);
}

if(stmt != NULL) {

    // Deallocate result set
    mysql_stmt_free_result(stmt); /* deallocate result set */

     if (mysql_stmt_close(stmt)) {
         errStr = "closing the statement failed ";
         errStr.append(mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

}

I call it like this

```
std::string errBuf;
int affected_rows = 0;
std::string sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM name WHERE (?) like name";

std::vector<MYSQL_BIND> paramList;  
std::vector<MYSQL_BIND> resultParamList;

char data[1024];
safe_strncpy(data,name,sizeof(data), __FILE__, __LINE__);

MYSQL_BIND param1;  
BindValue(&param1,MYSQL_TYPE_STRING,data,strlen(data),0,0);
paramList.push_back(param1);    

int32 count = 0;    

bool ret = true;

if(RunPreparedStatement(sql,paramList,errBuf,&affected_rows,true,&count)){
 ...
}
```

I previously had also a resultParamList instead of simple the ID and had the same error and thought it was related to return a list of values but that wasnt it.

Im receiving the warning as soon as the RunPreparedStatement method is finished.

Comment: `RunPreparedStatement` takes 8 arguments, you're only calling it with 6.

Comment: Sorry the header is bool RunPreparedStatement(std::string query, std::vector<MYSQL_BIND> paramList, std::string& errbuf, int* affected_rows, bool fetchResultID = false, int32* result_id=0, bool fetchInsertID = false, int32* last_insert_id=0);

Comment: Don't post it in a comment, edit the question.

Comment: I already did, just FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying another sample code i found the issue

```
int32 id = 0;
MYSQL_BIND resultParam1;    
BindValue(&resultParam1,MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG,&id,0,0,0);
```

im telling that the result type is MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG but im only giving it a int32 (unsigned int ) instead of unsigned long long.

So either change to MYSQL_TYPE_LONG or increase var size.